# Android Google Map в фрагменте и поддержка от SDK 16

Tags: android, android-sdk, google-maps-api, android-fragment, google-maps

Использую Google Map, разместил компоненту во фрагмент.

Вот разметка фрагмента:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchMy"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_track_changes_100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_circle_selector"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:onClick="onClickSearchMyLocation" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Вот сам код который работает на SDK 22 и SDK 23 :

```
public class fragment_new_order_map extends Fragment {
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_order_map, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap = mMapView.getMap();

        if (googleMap != null) {}   
}
```

В итоге начиная с SDK 16 = googleMap возвращается NULL.

Смотрим пример который есть в Android Studio и меняем все как там:

```
public class fragment_new_order_map extends Fragment implements  OnMapReadyCallback {

...

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_order_map, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {}
```

Но так выдает ошибку в принципе. Везде. Где то что то не правильно делаю.
Ошибка :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                          at ru.suite.name.project.fragments.fragment_new_order_map.onCreateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался!

Чтобы подключить карту в фрагменте:

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
if (googleMap != null) {}
```

Но возникла другая проблема. Но это тему для другого топа.